# Using Boto to connect to S3 with Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm trying to access AWS using Boto, and it's not working. I've installed Boto, and the boto.cfg in /etc.  Here's my code:

```
import requests, json
import datetime
import hashlib
import boto

conn = boto.connect_s3()
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "boto.py", line 4, in <module>
    import boto
  File "/home/mydir/public_html/boto.py", line 6, in <module>
    conn = boto.connect_s3()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect_s3'
```

What the hell? This isn't complicated.

Comment: Not sure if my error is related, but I'm getting boto/utils.py", line 171, in merge_meta
    if k.lower() in boto.s3.key.Key.base_user_settable_fields:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'key'

Answer (score 18):

It looks like the file you're working on is called `boto.py`. I think what's happening here is that your file is importing itself--Python looks for modules in the directory containing the file doing the import before it looks on your `PYTHONPATH`. Try changing the name to something else.

Comment: Note that you'll also need to delete the generated `boto.pyc` if it has been created.

Comment: Thanks for this. had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use the Connection classes.

e.g.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.sns.connection import SNSConnection
from boto.ses.connection import SESConnection

def connect_s3(self):
  return S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

def connect_sns(self):
  return SNSConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

def connect_ses(self):
  return SESConnection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do something similar to how I had to utilize the `EC2Connection` class in some of my code, which looks like this:

```
from boto.ec2.connection import EC2Connection
conn = EC2Connection(...)
```

Also, from their docs (http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html):

```
>>> from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
>>> conn = S3Connection('<aws access key>', '<aws secret key>')
```

EDIT: I know that doc page has the shortcut function you're trying to use, but I saw a similar problem when trying to do the same type of shortcut with EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all of your solutions, but none of them seem to work. I keep going over StackOverFlow as I cannot see anyone else not having this rather small issue. Kind of weird fact is that in the server it works like a charm. The issue is on my Mac

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and was facing the same error when using boto3 and moto to mock s3 bucket.

```
boto3.connect_s3()
```

I switched back my library to boto and it worked fine. It looks like boto3 has migrated connect_s3() to resources():

```
boto.connect_s3() //works
boto3.resources('s3')  //works
```

I could resolve similar issue for AWS Lambda too:

```
boto.connect_awslambda() //works
boto3.client('lambda')  //works
```